# Execute play from Ant script

Tags: java, ant, build, playframework, antbuilder

I'm looking for a way to run [`play dist`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionDist) through an Ant build script. I've looked into using the [`exec`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task but it is not working for me. Here is what I tried:

```
<target name="deploy">
    <exec executable="play">
        <arg value="dist" />
    </exec>    
</target>
```

I'm getting this error:

> `C:\Users\path\to\build.xml:39: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "play": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Play is already in my Path environment variable and I can execute it from the command line by typing `play` so that isn't the problem. I'm not allowed to use absolute paths due to sysadmin constraints.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up manually searching for the Play executable and storing the property to use in the `exec` task:

```
<exec executable="where" outputproperty="play.dir" osfamily="windows">
        <arg value="play.bat" />
</exec>
<exec executable="which" outputproperty="play.dir" osfamily="unix">
        <arg value="play" />
</exec>

<exec executable="${play.dir}" dir=" ... ">
        <arg value="dist" />
</exec>
```